# How can I access a variable outside a loop when I set in it inside the loop?

Tags: perl, loops

I wrote a quick Perl script to query the local DNS servers for an IP address, and I have a variable that needs to be declared within the scope of the loop, but it doesn't seem to be in scope outside of the loop.  The compiler is returning the errors

```
Global Symbol "$ipAddr" requires explicit package name
```

Here's the code

```
my $resolver = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;

my $dnsQuery = $resolver->search($hostIP[0]->getFirstChild->getData);

if ($dnsQuery) {
    foreach my $rr ($dnsQuery->answer) {
        next unless $rr->type eq "A";
        my $ipAddr = ip2dec($rr->address);
    }
}

print( "::".$ipAddr );
```

How would it be possible to declare a variable in this manner that would be accessible from outside of the loop?

Comment: mobrule has the answer to the question asked below.  I would offer one additional suggestion for the code... add a 'last;' as the last line inside the foreach loop.  In most cases here it likely isn't much of a performance issue since there are not likely many resource records in your answer but it's a good to be in the habit of leaving loops as soon as you've done what you needed to do.  It can really make a difference on heavy loops that could run millions of times, especially if you are done after the second iteration.  Otherwise, your code looks great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the `my $ipAddr` declaration outside the loop:

```
my $dnsQuery = $resolver->search($hostIP[0]->getFirstChild->getData);
my $ipAddr;
if ($dnsQuery) {
        foreach my $rr ($dnsQuery->answer) {
                next unless $rr->type eq "A";
                $ipAddr = ip2dec($rr->address);
        }
}
print("::".$ipAddr);
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out shortly after I posted, but got all kinds of errors when I tried it so I was wondering if that was still valid.

Comment: if you're not in "use strict" you can also just take off the "my"

Comment: Not using "use strict" is like drive 100 MPH without a seat belt -- a very bad idea unless you are absolutely sure you know what you are doing and if you think you know what you are doing, you're probably wrong.